# Making Area Chart with Two Variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

I have a data set of the Win/Loss record of the Boston Red Sox in 2018 which starts like:

```
Game,W/L,W,L
1,L,0,1
2,W,1,1
3,W,2,1
4,W,3,1
5,W,4,1
6,W,5,1
7,W,6,1
8,W,7,1
9,W,8,1
```

I want to convert this to a stacked area chart comparing `W` vs. `L` with respect to Game in `ggplot2`, but am struggling with how to set this up. I can get started using

```
rec = read.csv('redsox_record.csv')

ggplot(rec, aes(x=Game, y=W)) + geom_area()
```

but this only returns the chart for `W`, and I'm not sure how to include L as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
rec <- melt(rec[, c(1, 3, 4)], id.vars = 'Game')
ggplot(rec, aes(x=Game, y=value, fill = variable)) + geom_area()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. Didn't know about the melting option and that it would be necessary.